# How to specify custom name for ASPState database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-config, aspstate

I am facing the problem that I need multiple ASPState databases for different ASP.NET projects on the same db server, beacuse I really want to share the Session State db for those projects.

After doing some research (e.g. [here](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Store-Session-SQL-Server.aspx) and here), I created the first database using following command:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -E -S "fooserver" -ssadd -sstype "c" -d "FooProject.Sessions"
```

In the `<system.web>` section of my web.config, I have following entry:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="data source=fooserver;integrated security=True;database=FooProject.Sessions" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />
```

But when I try to Access the [`Session`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.session?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) property of my controller context, I get an NullReferenceException (Session is null).

When I set the `allowCustomSqlDatabase` attribute of the configuration entry to `false`, everything works fine.

What did I do wrong? It seems like no one else has this problem  Thank you in advance!

PS: Just tell me if I need to provide more information.

Comment: Did you really name your database with a `.` in it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, triple checked the name. Every database on the server has at least one dot in its name.

Comment: Well this is not recommended because many tools and libraries won't know to use square brackets around the name. You could try that (`database=[FooProject.Sessions]`), but I also recommend trying this technique against a database that *does not* use bad naming conventions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I tried enclosing the database name with square brackets, but without success.

Comment: I didn't have high confidence that would work. I still think you should try a simpler *and legal* database name, like `FooProject_Sessions`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I tried the name `CustomName` (without any special characters). I still receive the same error: `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Session.get returned null.`  Thank you very much for your help!